# Unable to mock method call using mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm writing a test case where I'm trying to  use mockito to avoid entering text through console. But on running the test case, it waits for something to be entered in console (which is again something I'm unable to do) instead of getting it from mockito. Would appreciate if someone can help. The test code looks like this:

```
SongsNameUpdater songsNameUpdater = new SongsNameUpdater();
bufferedReader = mock(BufferedReader.class);
when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("test Path");
songsNameUpdater.updateSongNames();
```

The main code is:

```
public class SongsNameUpdater {
       public void updateSongNames() throws IOException {
               bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
               String path = bufferedReader.readLine();
               System.out.println(path);
       }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass your BufferedReader mock e.g. like `updateSongNames(bufferedReader)` and not instantiating it within the method

Comment: can you please post ur modified code mindReader that got it working